# How to use one-way ANOVA for three groups?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, data

I want to reproduce the Example illustrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance#Example) using Mathematica 12.0. In this example **one-way** analysis is applied to the following three groups of values:

```
a1 = {6, 8, 4, 5, 3, 4};
a2 = {8, 12, 9, 11, 6, 8};
a3 = {13, 9, 11, 8, 7, 12};
data = Transpose[{a1,a2,a3}]
```

My problem is that I can not understand how to make ANOVA[data] perform a **one‐way** analysis.
Thank you in advance!

PS

I do know that I can use two-way analysis using steps described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/ANOVA.html). However, I am interested in one-way analysis results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your data according to the requirements in the documentation.

You will need two columns: the first column identifies the group; the second column contains the data.

So your first column should contain six 1's, six 2's, and six 3's (since you have 3 groups of size 6). Your second column will contain your data values.

Comment: Mike Z., 
Thank you so much!